# Queries in Power BI

Tags: dynamic, plsql, powerbi

Is it possible to filter data based on the user who login to the dashboard? 
How to get the user details on login?

Also is dynamic data filtering possible in power BI? If so please give some useful links.

Is it possible to filter data by SQL queries?

Answer (score 4):

There's a yes and a not yet on this one right now, but it is something we're looking into.  First the yes part: We support live data connectivity to Tabular models on premises hosted in SSAS. When you use that option, any row level security you implement in SSAS on premises is automatically applied.

Second the not yet part: we're looking to make this kind of security enforcement work more broadly across other data sources. We still in the requirements gathering phase for this.  Suggest you provide a detailed writeup of your requirements at support.powerbi.com so we can track this and get back to you when it's available.

Answer (score 2):

This is now possible using [Row Level Security](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/service-admin-rls).

You can define different roles that filter the data in different ways based on the user.

You can read the user by using `USERNAME()` or `USERPRINCIPLENAME()`.

Answer (score 1):

Power Bi uses the term Direct Query to pull live data from the database. This option is available when connecting to the database (after you click the Get Data button).

In the same screen while you are connecting to the database there are Advanced Options which allows you to pull data using a query.

As a side note Direct Query does not work with casting and has other limitations. Creating a view can allow more flexibility and pulling the data from the view can work better.

[For More Info](https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/powerbi-desktop-use-directquery/)